# Using another one application in one Iphone Application?

Tags: iphone

anytutorial to use good reader application in iphone sdk?
can I use Good reader application  in my Iphone APplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To launch another application you have to find out if they have published a protocol to use and then 'open' that URL. See [example](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-other-apps-within-an-iphone-application.html), but not sure if GoodReader has published a protocol or how to find out if they have. You could always contact the developer directly.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can't access another applications Sandbox or start another application via code, otherwise Apple will reject the app.</strike>   I stand corrected to the answer about URL schemes to launch another app.  You learn something new everyday.

You [can also] build the PDF functionality into your own app (i.e. use a UIWebView to do that for you).